# what happens to events after the object it references is disposed of?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

what happens if i link a method of some object to a delegate, and then dispose of the object?

Like this:

```
class Hunter
{
    public event Action Shoot;

    public execute()
    {
        Form formBabySeal = new Form();

        Shoot += formBabySeal.Close;

        formBabySeal.Show();
        formBabySeal.Close(); //Dispose Form

        if (Shoot != null)
        {
             Shoot(); //event is null?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Shoot is not null, but it doesn't do anything either

Comment: @hcb: What do you think it should do? The form is already closed! Also, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formBabySeal` is not `null` just because you dispose it. So, `formBabySeal.Close()` will be called.

Your code is equivalent to this when looking at what methods are called:

```
Form formBabySeal = new Form();

formBabySeal.Show();
formBabySeal.Close(); //Dispose Form
formBabySeal.Close();
```

This will close the form (first call to `Close`) and the second call won't do anything, because the form is already closed.

However, as Steve points out in the comment section, your code will introduce a memory leak, because `Shoot` still holds a reference to the `Close` method of `formBabySeal` and because of this `formBabySeal` will be kept alive as long as the instance of the class `Hunter` is alive.

Comment: And I like to add that this is a common way of introducing memory leaks, since although the object is disposed, it is still referenced by the application and will therefore not be collected by the GC.

Comment: The documentation specifies a different scenario in which the exception gets raised.

Comment: "Condition: You cannot call this method from the Activated event when WindowState is set to Maximized."

Comment: Hm, i've been trying your code (first codeblock) and it seems the Close function doesn't throw an exception when the form is disposed. This means either the form isn't really disposed of or the close function handles it itself, which is weird because it should be disposed of.

Comment: And steven's comment answered that. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

WinDBG with SOS extensions has a way to show GCRoot of any object.  This might give you more clues.